# What data can I cache here to avoid recurring DB calls?

Tags: java, math, caching, statistics

So my requirement is that I will be pulling currency rate data of 1000 days from today for calculating spread in BPS for each day and average and standard deviation of the spreads for that period. This process must happen on every business day. Since there are multiple currencies (say 200), we'll have to get 200 * 1000 = 200k records on regular basis.
To avoid this, I thought of pulling the 1000 records for each currency one time, calculate avg and cache the average value. Then use the formula mentioned here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1567342 to calculate new averages by deleting the oldest and adding new record.

Subract value :

```
average = ((average * nbValues) - value) / (nbValues - 1);
```

Add value :

```
average = average + ((value - average) / nbValues);
```

Now the problem is with calculating standard deviation using the below formula:

```
S = [(Sum of (xi – x)^2)/n-1]^1/2

where

n = number of data points
xi = values of the data
x = Mean
```

This requires each one of the values xi for calculating standard deviation. How can I approach to design a solution in an efficient manner for this problem?

As mentioned above, new averages can be calculated using cached avg values that works fine.
However, not sure on how to approach for calculating std deviation without making DB calls to retrieve all thousand days records on daily basis and not caching huge amounts of data.

Comment: If you are using mysql there is a stdev function available.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Well, unfortunately this operation won't happen directly on the DB records. There is a lot of selection/filtering that happens on the fetched data

Answer (score 0):

You could work on a derived formula for standard deviation

Consider

```
sum_x = sum of all xi
sum_x_square = sum of all xi^2
x = Mean of xi
```

The Standard deviation can be written as

```
stdev = sqrt((sum_x_square / n) - (x * x))
```

so you can cache the running sum of xi and sum of xi^2 and work only on the incremental data.

**Derivation of the formula**

[image]

**Resource**

https://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/science-fair/variance-and-standard-deviation

Comment: Can you let me know how you arrived at this formula? I just tried it with sample data and it gave me incorrect standard deviation.

Comment: Here is the derivation of the formula. https://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/science-fair/variance-and-standard-deviation. Please take a look. I think I provided the right formula